# php remove surrounding empty arrays from menu array

Tags: php, arrays, menu, yii2

Hi I am trying to build a better dynamic menu than the one I currently have using arrays

I am however having trouble removing the surrounding tier arrays which is preventing yii or bootstrap from recognizing it as a menu as it cannot see the label elements.

my code

```
menu=array();
$loggedOut=array();
$loggedInMenu=array();
if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
{
    //sandard menu
    array_push( $loggedOut,array("label"=>"HOME","url"=>"/site/indexl1","options"=>array("class"=>"l1")));
    array_push( $loggedOut,array("label"=>"SERVICES","url"=>"/site/services","options"=>array("class"=>"l2")));
    array_push( $loggedOut,array("label"=>"OUR VISION","url"=>"/site/vision","options"=>array("class"=>"l3")));
    //products
    array_push( $loggedOut,array("Label"=>"PRODUCTS","items"=>array(
        "label"=>"TAPER BUCKET","url"=>"/site/taper","options"=>array("class"=>"l41")
        ,"label"=>"DIPPER","url"=>"/site/dipper","options"=>array("class"=>"l42")
         ,"label"=>"LOADBODY","url"=>"/site/loadbody","options"=>array("class"=>"l43")
          ,"label"=>"DRAGLINE BUCKET","url"=>"/site/dragline","options"=>array("class"=>"l44")
          ,"label"=>"BACK HOE","url"=>"/site/backhoe","options"=>array("class"=>"l45")
        ,"label"=>"FACE SHOVEL","url"=>"/site/shovel","options"=>array("class"=>"l45")
        )));
    array_push( $loggedOut,array("label"=>"CONTACT","url"=>"/site/contacts","options"=>array("class"=>"l5")));
    array_push( $loggedOut,array("label"=>"PUBLICATIONS","url"=>"/site/pubs","options"=>array("class"=>"l6")));
}
else
{

}
array_push($menu,$loggedOut);
```

Output I am getting:

> array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => HOME [url] => /site/indexl1 [options] => Array ( [class] => l1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [label] => SERVICES [url] => /site/services [options] => Array ( [class] => l2 ) ) [2] => Array ( [label] => OUR VISION [url] => /site/vision [options] => Array ( [class] => l3 ) ) [3] => Array ( [Label] => PRODUCTS [items] => Array ( [label] => FACE SHOVEL [url] => /site/shovel [options] => Array ( [class] => l45 ) ) ) [4] => Array ( [label] => CONTACT [url] => /site/contacts [options] => Array ( [class] => l5 ) ) [5] => Array ( [label] => PUBLICATIONS [url] => /site/pubs [options] => Array ( [class] => l6 ) ) ) )

Output I want:

> [0] => Array ( [label] => HOME [url] => /site/indexl1 [options] => Array ( [class] => l1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [label] => SERVICES [url] => /site/services [options] => Array ( [class] => l2 ) ) [2] => Array ( [label] => OUR VISION [url] => /site/vision [options] => Array ( [class] => l3 ) ) [3] => Array ( [Label] => PRODUCTS [items] => Array ( [label] => FACE SHOVEL [url] => /site/shovel [options] => Array ( [class] => l45 ) ) ) [4] => Array ( [label] => CONTACT [url] => /site/contacts [options] => Array ( [class] => l5 ) ) [5] => Array ( [label] => PUBLICATIONS [url] => /site/pubs [options] => Array ( [class] => l6 )

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
array_push($menu,$loggedOut);
```

Please try:

```
$menu = $loggedOut;
```

Better is to array_push the elements directly to $menu, then your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ,I have tried that and I still end up with one array too much,that only removes one if that makes sense.

Comment: The correct method for creating dynamic menus in bootstrap 3 is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060086/how-to-build-dynamic-menu-in-yii2